# Discrete Random Variables and Probability Mass Function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

###### Setting

In my setting, I have an infinite sequence of unfair coin flips (0.7 probability for head and 0.3 probability for tail): I assume that I need one random variable $X_i$ (for each $i\geq 0$) for each coin flip $i$.
Intuitively, I assume to get for each $i$ a PMF $p_{X_i}$ with $p_{X_i}(Head)=0.7$ and $p_{X_i}(Tail)=0.3$.

However, according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition), each $X_i$ must be a function $X_i:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ for some probability space $(\Omega_1,\sigma_1,P)$ and measurable space $(\Omega_2,\sigma_2)$.

###### My question

What are $\Omega_1$, $\sigma_1$, $P$, $\Omega_2$, $\sigma_2$, and $X_i$ in this case?
Also, are all $X_i$ equal to each other?

Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Measure-theoretic_definition) and adapting the variable names.

> In more intuitive terms, a member of $\Omega_1$ is a possible outcome,
> a member of $\sigma_1$ is a measurable subset of possible outcomes,
> the function $P$ gives the probability of each such measurable subset,
> $\Omega_2$ represents the set of values that the random variable can take (such as the set of real numbers), and
> a member of $\sigma_2$ is a "well-behaved" (measurable) subset of $\Omega_2$ (those for which the probability may be determined).
> The random variable is then a function from any outcome to a quantity, such that the outcomes leading to any useful subset of quantities for the random variable have a well-defined probability.

I guess that I do not understand the difference between $\Omega_1$ (possible outcomes) and $\Omega_2$ (values the random variable can take).

###### Confused thinking

My following reasoning is presumably not helpful but shows my confused thought process.

The PMF $p_{X_i}$ must have type $\Omega_2\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ indicating that $\Omega_2=\{Head,Tail\}$.

I assume that $\sigma_2=2^{\Omega_2}$: this may not be the only possible case but it  satisfies the requirement that $\sigma_2$ must be a sigma algebra for $(\Omega_2,\sigma_2)$ to be a measurable space.

At this point I am not sure what $(\Omega_1,\sigma_1)$ can be (except being equal to $(\Omega_2,\sigma_2)$, which would make the formalization somewhat strange and redundant in appearance in my opinion).

Sure, for the PMF from above to be obtained: $P$ must be defined suitably in the sense that it must assign the probabilities $0$, $0.3$, $0.7$, and $1$ to suitable sets of $0$, $1$, $1$, and $2$ elements.
So doesn't this mean that $\sigma_1=2^{\Omega_1}$ and that $\Omega_1$ has two elements (unless there are more elements that do not contribute to resulting probabilities)?
This would mean that $(\Omega_1,\sigma_1)$ and $(\Omega_2,\sigma_2)$ are possible isomorphic...

Comment: Typically, in situations like yours, $\Omega_1$ is a space of sequences, such as $\{U,T\}^{\mathbb N}$.  $\Omega_2$ is in your case the set $\{H,T\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about $\Omega_2$.

We can not choose $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2$ - we would have too little number of outcomes. Possible outcomes in such setup should describe all values of $X_i$, so given $\omega \in \Omega_1$ we can tell what was result of first, second and so on tosses.

One possibility would be to consider $\Omega_1$ be exactly that - infinite sequences of letters H and T, then we will have $X_i(\omega) = \omega_i$.

We now need to define $\sigma_1$ and $P$. The simplest way to do this is to define it is to use Carathéodory's extension theorem. We start with cylindrical algebra - algebra generated by sets $\{\omega \in \Omega_1| \omega_1 \in \alpha_1, \ldots, \omega_n \in \alpha_n\}$ - we fix some finite number of coordinates, and the rest are arbitrary. Exercise: how would you define measure of such set? Then we take $\sigma$-algebra generated by these sets, and extend measure to it by extension theorem.

Alternatively, instead of defining $\Sigma_1$ manually, we can use Kolmogorov extension theorem to prove that suitable space exists: we define finite-dimensional distributions (that consider only finite number of tosses), and then this theorem says that there is a space that can support distribution of all coins. This theorem is the reason we usually don't care about exact probability space, only about distributions - the probability space always can be constructed, and all interesting questions are about distributions, not the space.

Comment: Thanks! To my understanding $X_i$ basically /projects/ to the impact of one probabilistic event /forgetting/ all the other information also present in a full concrete observation $\omega$. 
Clearly, all impacts of probabilistic events must be in that $\omega$ for that reason.
However, if only considering finite paths of varying length, then a path of length $20$ would not define a random variable $X_{100}$; however, the random variables are defined for all paths $\omega\in\Omega_1$; so how would $X_{100}$ be defined for a path of length $20$?

Comment: What is "path" here? If we build $\Omega_1$ explicitly, $\omega$ should include values of all $X_i$.

Comment: With path, I meant one sequence of elements of $\{H,T\}$. So, if we define $\Omega_1=\bigcup_{0\leq i\leq 10}\{H,T\}^i$ to be the set of all such sequences of length up to 10, then there is some sequence $\omega_{2}=HH$ and some sequence $\omega_{3}=HHH$. If $X_{3}$ refers to the 3rd coin toss, then what would $X_{3}(\omega_{2})$ be? Would be define it so be some dummy element? Or are finite sequences as elements of $\Omega_1$ therefore not possible since every $\omega\in\Omega_1$ must include all $X_i$?

Comment: Yes, if we define $\Omega_1$ this way, it should contain only infinite sequences.

Comment: Ok, this is very interesting! I also wonder what happens when there are two different things happening random (e.g., the coin from before and a 6-sided dice) and tossed in different orders in different paths $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ that are given as sequences over $\{H,T,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Then does $X_1(\omega_1)=H$  and $X_1(\omega_1)=4$ make sense (when the first event in those two paths is $H$ and $4$ respectively)? Afterall, $X_1$ must map to a common set, which must therefore     contain all possible values $\{H,T,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (rather than having different kinds of random variables).

Comment: $X_1(\omega_1) = H$ and $X_1(\omega_1) = 4$ doesn't make sense - after all, $X_1$ is a function and should have single value on fixed argument. If in different experiments you have different order of coin and dice, you can have, for example, $X_1(\omega_1) = H$ and $X_2(\omega_1) = 4$.

Comment: I misstyped: I meant $X_1(\omega_1)=H$ and $X_1(\omega_2)=4$... of course $X_1$ needs to be a function. But it also needs to have a single codomain, which may therefore need to include elements that appear to not be related. Still, there would then only be random variables with the single codomain $\{H,T,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ instead of random variables with either $\{H,T\}$ or $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ as codomain, right?

Comment: If you perform infinite number of actions, where each action is coin or dice toss - then yes. If, for example, you are guaranteed that you will have at least one coin toss, you can also introduce a random variable $Y_1$ on the same $\Omega_1$, that gives result of coin toss. Usually, what exactly is structure $\Omega_1$ isn't important - it's important that you can define necessary random variables on it.